# Manage process in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

I made a fast and simple WPM (WriteProcessMemory) for Android. Any suggestion is welcome.

```
bool bChangedProtect;
cout << search_results[cur_result].size() << " found.\n" << endl; 
for (int xy = 0; xy < search_results[cur_result].size(); xy++) 
{ 
   bChangedProtect = false;
   if (ReadProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)search_results[cur_result][xy],&sResult,8,nullptr) == 8) 
   {
      if (sResult==double_val) 
      {
     cout <<"item #" << xy << "\t";
         if (VirtualQueryEx(phandle, (void*)search_results[cur_result][xy], &mBI, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)))
         {
             if ((mBI.Protect & PAGE_WRITECOPY) || (mBI.Protect & PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY))
             {
                 cout << hex << search_results[cur_result][xy] << " was WRITE_COPY or EXEC_WRITE_COPY ..skipping, just because." << endl;
                 continue;
             }
             else if ((mBI.Protect & PAGE_EXECUTE) || (mBI.Protect & PAGE_EXECUTE_READ))
             { 
                 if (VirtualProtectEx(phandle,(void*)search_results[cur_result][xy],8,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&OLDPROTECT))
                 {
                     cout << hex << search_results[cur_result][xy] << " Was EXEC or EXEC_R --> VirtualProtectEx(EXEC_RW) SUCCESS" << endl;
                    bChangedProtect = true;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     cout << hex << search_results[cur_result][xy] << " Was EXEC or EXEC_R --> VirtualProtectEx(EXEC_RW) FAIL. skipping write." << endl;
                     continue;
                 }
             }
             else if (mBI.Protect & PAGE_READONLY)
             {
                 if (VirtualProtectEx(phandle, (void*)search_results[cur_result][xy],8,PAGE_READWRITE,&OLDPROTECT))
                 { 
                 cout << hex << search_results[cur_result][xy] << " Was READ_ONLY --> VirtualProtectEx(READ_WRITE) SUCCESS" << endl;
                 bChangedProtect = true;
                 }
                 else
                 { 
                 cout << hex << search_results[cur_result][xy] << " Was READ_ONLY --> VirtualProtectEx(READ_WRITE) FAIL. skipping write." << endl;
                 continue;
                 }
             }
             //if we get here, apparently it's writable (and not copy-forward). 
                         if (!bChangedProtect)
                           cout << hex << search_results[cur_result][xy]; //will be first time we show the addr. todo: re-work logic because this feels awkward.

             if (WriteProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)search_results[cur_result][xy],&double_ans,8,nullptr))
             {
                 cout << " WriteProcessMemory() OK!" << endl;
             }
             else
             {
                 cout << " WriteProcessMemory() FAIL!" << endl;
                 if (VirtualQueryEx(phandle,(void*)search_results[cur_result][xy],&mBI,sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)))
                 {
                     cout <<"Current Protect: " << hex << mBI.Protect << endl;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     cout <<"Current Protect: Unknown. VirtualQueryEx() Failed -- but why? -- does this happen?" << endl;
                 }   
             }
             if (bChangedProtect)
             {
                 DWORD idk = 0;
                 if (VirtualProtectEx(phandle,(void*)search_results[cur_result][xy],8,OLDPROTECT,&idk)) //not sure if you should use same var for old and new protect. will it set 'oldProtect' to the old protection before writing. is a temporary used? idk. try if you care.
                 {
                     cout << hex << search_results[cur_result][xy] << " VirtualProtectEx(ORIG) SUCCESS" << endl;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     cout << hex << search_results[cur_result][xy] << " VirtualProtectEx(ORIG) FAIL -- does this happen?" << endl;
                 }
             }
         }
         else
         {
             cout <<"VirtualQueryEx FAILED for " << hex << search_results[cur_result][xy] << ". Skipping." << endl;
         }
      }
      else
      {
          cout << hex << search_results[cur_result][xy] << " sResult != double_val ... It was when we scanned, but not now. Skipped." << endl;
      }
   }
   else
   {
       cout << hex << search_results[cur_result][xy] << " ReadProcessMemory() fails" << endl;
   }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean for Android? That's clearly the Windows API that you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Prefer to define a variable as late and in the inner-most scope possible.
   Non-trivial class-types are a common exception where avoiding destruction and re-creation might be more performant.
2. Your indentation isn't really consistent, consider using your auto-formatter of choice.
3. You seem to suffer from severe adoration of braces. Still, you didn't use them in one place. Why?
4. Do you know that `std::hex` persists after being applied to a stream until explicitly countermanded?
5. Adding a reference for `search_results[cur_result]` at the start, aside from possibly being more performant, would also reduce the code considerably.

   The same for `thatexpression[xy]` at the start of every loop. Actually, if you didn't need `xy` for some reason, using a range-for-loop would be better.
6. `using namespace std;` is a bad idea, avoid it: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)
7. Consider first handling the error-case and getting it out of the way to reduce nesting.
8. You should learn how to simplify basic bitwise operations:

   ```
   if((mBI.Protect & PAGE_WRITECOPY) || (mBI.Protect & PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY))
   ```

   Is the same as:

   ```
   if(mBI.Protect & (PAGE_WRITECOPY | PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY))
   ```
9. Avoid using a type as argument to `sizeof`, use the appropriate expression instead.
   (`sizeof mBI` instead of `sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)`)
10. You should redo a basic tutorial if you don't know what pass-by-value and pass-by-reference mean, and when you have each in C++.
    Yes, `OLDPROTECT` (Why all upper-case? It's not a macro!) is safe to use there.
11. Is there any specific reason you explicitly flush the output-stream on every newline, or do you just like flushing your performance down the drain?
12. Why do you use all the C-style casts to `void*`? I'm very suspicious of casts, and because I don't know the type of `search_results[cur_result][xy]`, I have no idea whether the cast is just superfluous and bad form, neccessary due to bad choice of types, or an outright bug the compiler had the impertinence to complain about.
13. We do not see how/if you handle concurrency-issues.

---

After applying everything I can be sure works (aka not #12 and taking a gamble on #11):

```
auto&& srcr = search_results[cur_result];
using std::cout;
cout << std::hex << srcr.size() << " found.\n\n"; 
for (int xy = 0; xy < srcr.size(); xy++) {
    auto&& current = srcr[xy];
    if (ReadProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)current,&sResult,8,nullptr) != 8) {
        cout << current << " ReadProcessMemory() fails\n";
        continue;
    }
    if (sResult!=double_val) {
        cout << current << " sResult != double_val ... It was when we scanned, but not now. Skipped.\n";
        continue;
    }
    cout <<"item #" << xy << "\t";
    if (!VirtualQueryEx(phandle, (void*)current, &mBI, sizeof mBI)) {
        cout <<"VirtualQueryEx FAILED for " << current << ". Skipping.\n";
        continue;
    }
    if (mBI.Protect & (PAGE_WRITECOPY | PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY)) {
        cout << current << " was WRITE_COPY or EXEC_WRITE_COPY ..skipping, just because.\n";
        continue;
    }
    bool bChangedProtect = false;
    if (mBI.Protect & (PAGE_EXECUTE | PAGE_EXECUTE_READ)) {
        if (!VirtualProtectEx(phandle,(void*)current,8,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&OLDPROTECT)) {
            cout << current << " Was EXEC or EXEC_R --> VirtualProtectEx(EXEC_RW) FAIL. skipping write.\n";
            continue;
        }
        cout << current << " Was EXEC or EXEC_R --> VirtualProtectEx(EXEC_RW) SUCCESS\n";
        bChangedProtect = true;
    } else if (mBI.Protect & PAGE_READONLY) {
        if (!VirtualProtectEx(phandle, (void*)current,8,PAGE_READWRITE,&OLDPROTECT)) {
            cout << current << " Was READ_ONLY --> VirtualProtectEx(READ_WRITE) FAIL. skipping write.\n";
            continue;
        }
        cout << current << " Was READ_ONLY --> VirtualProtectEx(READ_WRITE) SUCCESS\n";
        bChangedProtect = true;
    }
    //if we get here, apparently it's writable (and not copy-forward).
    if (!bChangedProtect)
        cout << current; //will be first time we show the addr. todo: re-work logic because this feels awkward.
    if (WriteProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)current,&double_ans,8,nullptr)) {
        cout << " WriteProcessMemory() OK!\n";
    } else {
        cout << " WriteProcessMemory() FAIL!\n";
        if (VirtualQueryEx(phandle,(void*)current,&mBI,sizeof mBI))
            cout <<"Current Protect: " << mBI.Protect << '\n';
        else
            cout <<"Current Protect: Unknown. VirtualQueryEx() Failed -- but why? -- does this happen?\n";
    }
    if (bChangedProtect) {
        if (VirtualProtectEx(phandle,(void*)current,8,OLDPROTECT,&OLDPROTECT))
            cout << current << " VirtualProtectEx(ORIG) SUCCESS\n";
        else
            cout << current << " VirtualProtectEx(ORIG) FAIL -- does this happen?\n";
    }
}
```